# How will Websockets and Async Http methods and handlers help in asp.net webpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, preview

From the developer preview [What’s New for ASP.NET 4.5 and Web Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420390%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) it seems we get to use Websockets and Async Http methods,Handlers

- What significance do these provide for a web developer from a programming perspective?
- What are their real benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async is the best way to do long-running IO-bound operations: calling external network resources, long-running database queries, and so on. You should understand the [pros and cons of asynchronous operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) before using it. The main reason to use async operations in ASP.NET is to [release the working thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET) while performing IO, to allow this thread to be used to process subsequent requests.

Websockets are used to send frequent server-to-client notifications and updates. Classic examples of such applications are web chat and stock ticker. There are some alternatives to websockets: [Ajax long-polling and Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), Flash/Java applets, [Silverlight client with WCF duplex service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).